# formatting json date adding a 0

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have an Handlebar helper call findHour that will return the hour as hh:mm but for 2:4 (2hrs40) it doesn't add the 0 at the end of it.

```
var heure_intervention = "2000-01-01T07:04:57Z"


   Handlebars.registerHelper( "findHour", function ( heure_intervention ){
        a= new Date(heure_intervention);
        return (a.getHours() +":"+ a.getMinutes());
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/PjUyX/)

Comment: getMinutes() would return  `40` if it is forty minutes after the hour. The only time it would return `4` is if it's four minutes after, e.g. `2:4` would be 4 minutes after two o'clock, not forty minutes. You mean you want `2:04`?

Comment: yes you are righ! I wasn't clear enought in my explicaion

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
...
return ( ( '0' + a.getHours() ).slice(-2) +":"+ ( '0' + a.getMinutes() ).slice(-2));
```